# Remove or hide controller name from url in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, controller

How can I remove controller name from url . I have two controller

```
 home and admin
```

and the url's are

```
 http://domain.com/likes/home/post/sports/20-Athletes-Who-Profited-While-in-College-/12

  home/post
```

and

```
  http://domain.com/likes/admin/ad_managment/edit/2

  http://domain.com/likes/admin/meta_tags_home/edit/2

   admin/ad_managment   admin/meta_tags_home
```

I have already used this

```
   $route['(:any)/(:any)/(:num)'] = "home/post/$1";
```

It works for this URL

```
    http://domain.com/likes/home/post/sports/20-Athletes-Who-Profited-While-in-College-/12
```

admin is not working. Basically I want to remove home/post Leave admin controller it doesn't matter

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "home/post/$1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://your-site.com/';
And in your routes.php

$route['default_controller'] = 'main';
```

Through this method you can remove controller name from url.

Comment: routes.php
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:num)'] = "home/post/$1";

Answer (score 0):

check user guide of codeigniter and in this [example](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/news_section.html) see how the routing done.
Read more about code-igniter routing